# WebGL GL_INVALID_OPERATION out of range error

Tags: arrays, webgl

All.I'm kind of new to webgl but I checked the resources about this error.I am trying to draw a single square right next to the my circle.I drew the circle after that ı added 4 indices for square and organize the drawArrays to based on that.But ı am getting this error :

> GL ERROR : GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0

Also checked my bounds and indexes but there is no problem about that here is the code :

```
var vPosition,angle=10,j=1,xr=0.2,yr=0.2,rad;
var transformationMatrix, transformationMatrixLoc;

window.onload = function init()
{

canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );

if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }
gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
//  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
gl.useProgram( program );

vertices = [
   vec2(0,0)
];

for(var i =0 ; i<=360 ; i+=10)
{
   vertices.push(vec2(xr*Math.cos(i*(Math.PI/180)),yr*Math.sin(i* 
   (Math.PI/180))));
}

 vertices.push(vec2(0.20,0));
 vertices.push(vec2(0.25,-0.05));
 vertices.push(vec2(0.3,0));
 vertices.push(vec2(0.25,0.05));

vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

// Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

transformationMatrixLoc = 
 gl.getUniformLocation(program,"transformationMatrix" );
render();
 }


render(){
gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
var MStack = [] ;

var transformationMatrix = mat4();
MStack.push(transformationMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv( transformationMatrixLoc, false, 
flatten(transformationMatrix) );
gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, vec4(red, green, blue, 1.0));

gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertices.length-4 );

transformationMatrix = MStack.pop();
MStack.push(transformationMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv( transformationMatrixLoc, false, 
flatten(transformationMatrix) );

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN,vertices.length-4,vertices.length);
gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, vec4(red, green, blue, 1.0));

window.requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

I hope you guys help me.Really thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The data array which is passed to [`.bufferData()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.5) has to be an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer).</s>

Use [`Float32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) to create an array of 32-bit floating point numbers. This corresponds to the `gl.FLOAT` type in the specification of the array of generic vertex attribute data:

`gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(flatten(vertices)), gl.STATIC_DRAW );`

Note, the size of the buffer objects data store is determined by the size of the array buffer.

---

The last parameter to [`.drawArrays()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.11) is the number of vertices to be rendered, rather than the index of the last attribute:

```js
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, vertices.length-4, 4);
```

Comment: I used the Float32Array but getting the same error.

Comment: AFAICT the library most of this student questions use is [this one](https://github.com/esangel/WebGL) in which `flatten` returns a `Float32Array`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet. Next time please post a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)
that reproduces your issue

Things I needed to fix in the code you posted

1. The code didn't include shaders

   I guessed some shaders that seemed to match the code

   ```
    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute  vec4 vPosition;
    uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
    void main() 
    {
        gl_Position = transformationMatrix*vPosition;
    } 
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision highp float;
    uniform vec4 color;
    void
    main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = color;
    }
    </script>
   ```
2. The code didn't define a canvas

   I added one with an id that matched the code

   ```
    <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
   ```
3. The code didn't link to the scripts you're using. Things like `vec2` and `flatten` used in JavaScript are not part of WebGL. They are part of some library. Without those we can't know what your code does

   I guessed it was these: https://github.com/esangel/WebGL and so I included them by adding

   ```
    <script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
    <script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>
   ```
4. The code didn't define or look up `colorLoc` for the `color` uniform location.
5. The code didn't define `red`, `green` and `blue`.

Assuming all of those existed in your actual code then I'm guessing the issue was this line

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN,vertices.length-4,vertices.length);
```

It should probably have been

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertices.length);
```

The arguments to `drawArrays` are

```
gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
```

where `primitiveType` is the type of primitive to draw. `offset` is the number of vertices to skip in the attributes you have configured and `count` is the number of vertices to process.

```js
var vPosition, angle = 10,
  j = 1,
  xr = 0.2,
  yr = 0.2,
  colorLoc,
  rad;
var transformationMatrix, transformationMatrixLoc;

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
  gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);

  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL isn't available");
  }
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

  var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
  gl.useProgram(program);

  vertices = [
    vec2(0, 0)
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i <= 360; i += 10) {
    vertices.push(vec2(xr * Math.cos(i * (Math.PI / 180)), yr * Math.sin(i *
      (Math.PI / 180))));
  }

  vertices.push(vec2(0.20, 0));
  vertices.push(vec2(0.25, -0.05));
  vertices.push(vec2(0.3, 0));
  vertices.push(vec2(0.25, 0.05));

  vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
  vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

  transformationMatrixLoc =
    gl.getUniformLocation(program, "transformationMatrix");
  colorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "color");
  render();
}

function render() {
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  var MStack = [];
  const red = 1;
  const green = 0.5;
  const blue = 0.25;

  var transformationMatrix = mat4();
  MStack.push(transformationMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(transformationMatrixLoc, false,
    flatten(transformationMatrix));
  gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, vec4(red, green, blue, 1.0));

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertices.length - 4);

  transformationMatrix = MStack.pop();
  MStack.push(transformationMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(transformationMatrixLoc, false,
    flatten(transformationMatrix));

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertices.length);
  gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, vec4(red, green, blue, 1.0));

  window.requestAnimFrame(render);
}

init();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute  vec4 vPosition;
uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
void main() 
{
    gl_Position = transformationMatrix*vPosition;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision highp float;
uniform vec4 color;
void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
</script>
```

One more thing the code did, it use an outdated way of starting using

```
window.onload = function init() { ...
```

A more modern way is just to put your scripts at the bottom of your page instead of the top and call `init` directly. Otherwise use `window.addEventListener('load', function init() { ...` as that will let more than one script init things on the page.

You might find [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org) helpful.